# How to make obfuscation + error reporting?

Tags: obfuscation, error-reporting

Good day!

I want to distribute the c# application and want protect it.
 I need:

1. obfuscation - protection of the source code + text resource files.
2. error reporting - a report on Unhandled Error.
3. clear view obfuscated stack trace
4. ensure there are no changes to source code.

What problems can get out due to the obfuscation (eg serialization / deserialization / reflection / globalization)? Appreciate the complexity of solutions this problems?

What methods / tools / approaches you recommend?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 4):

Disclaimer: I work for Red Gate.

[SmartAssembly](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/smartassembly) does what you're after. For your points in turn:

1) It does control flow obfuscation, method / field renaming, compression / encryption of resources and embedded strings, and separation of methods from their containing classes.

2) Automated error reporting automatically detects and reports unhandled execptions (it also grabs and sends the stack trace, values of all local variables, and some general system info).

3) The obfuscated stack trace gets decoded again on your machine so you can see it in clear view.

4) Not 100% that I know what you mean by this, but tamper protection prevents the app from running at all if any modifications are made to it. If you mean you don't want to make changes to your own source code, it is run as a post-build process so doesn't need any changes to be made to the source.

Re problems you might get with obfuscation, by far the most common are because of reflection (as a result WPF often causes problems), and data binding causes lots of issues too. Most obfuscators should let you exclude individual types and methods which have problems with reflection, though obviously that leaves those types and methods unprotected.

There are other obfuscators too - I know a couple of people who use one from PreEmptive called dotfuscator.

Answer (score 1):

[Crypto Obfuscator](http://www.ssware.com/cryptoobfuscator/obfuscator-net.htm) supports all the features you are looking for including obfuscation, code-protection as well as [Exception Reporting](http://www.ssware.com/cryptoobfuscator/exception-reporting.htm) (with automatic de-obfuscation as well as full values of all method parameters and local variables).

Another unique feature of Crypto Obfuscator is the Warnings tab shown after obfuscation. This lists all lines of code in your assemblies which can potentially cause the obfuscated assembly to fail. SO you don't have to shoot in the dark trying to figure out why obfuscated assemblies are not working.

DISCLAIMER: I work for LogicNP Software, the developer of Crypto Obfuscator.